# Raspberry PI 5 RDP

Tags: rdp

I am trying to use the RDP session for a R-Pi 5.  I can connect however the screen goes black and then drops.  Does anyone have some suggestions.  I have tried using a different users, disabling various items but none seem to to work.

Comment: How have you set up the RDP server on the pi?